How to (re)name a stripped (unnamed) LLDB symbol?
TL;DR
I’m trying to debug a binary that’s been stripped, thus missing symbol names for some procedures. Is there some way I can — even if only for the session — name particular unnamed/stripped procedures for debugging convenience?
Re-compiling the binary with those symbols (and even perhaps debug information) is not an option.

In More Detail...
When LLDB imports an image, it seems to automatically name all procedures that are absent from the symbol table with a ___lldb_unnamed_symbolXXX[1], where XXX is the symbol index, in numerically increasing order of (runtime) load address. When printing the symbol table of a binary with im dump symt <image>, LLDB labels these auto-named procs as Synthetic Symbols[2].
I’d like to be able to tag these Synthetic Symbols with specific names somehow — even if temporarily, only for the duration of the LLDB debug session; I want to be able to use the name functionally too, e.g. setting breakpoints with br set -n myRenamedProc -s myBinary. Importantly, I want the name to be displayed in place of the synthetic auto-generated name (i.e. ___lldb_unnamed_symbolXXX). So ideally, instead of a solution that substitutes the existing auto-generated name on-the-fly, it would be nice to replace it.
Related Questions
N.B.: Unlike in this post and this one, neither do I remember what the original methods were called, nor do I wish to use the original names in any way. In this post the OP suggests that they may want to achieve something similar to what I want — an alias to an existing symbol — as a prospective solution to another underlying issue, but it remains unexplored. Besides, I want the name to reflect, not just be a functional alias; i.e., I’m looking to replace the unhelpful ___lldb_unnamed_symbolXXX name so that references to the procedure (e.g. when printing disassembled instructions with di, or the name shown in the backtrace) then use the new name.
Had it not been for this requirement, the solution in this post makes for good aliases using function pointers.
Example
Here’s an excerpt from the LLDB-reported symbol-table of the binary in question:
(lldb) im dump symt firmwarepasswd
Symtab, file = <path-to-my-binary>, num_symbols = 68:
               Debug symbol
               |Synthetic symbol
               ||Externally Visible
               |||
Index   UserID DSX Type            ... Name
------- ------ --- --------------- ... ----------------------------------
...
[   42]     42  S  Code            ... ___lldb_unnamed_symbol42
...

I’d like to be able to rename ___lldb_unnamed_symbol42 to, e.g., WriteEfiVariable.
I’m aware that more sophisticated debugging/disassembly tools like IDA Pro and Hopper — both freemium pieces of software — are capable of doing this, but I couldn’t find anything relevant for LLDB. Although an LLDB solution is preferred, any solution with a FOSS (debugger) tool works too. Maybe this is trivial in GDB and I need to switch?


Context & Environment

The executable in question was originally written in Objective-C, its source code has since been misplaced. This post should also be just as valid for C/C++ files as well, though.
lldb-1400.0.38.17 (LLVM/clang 14.0.0, clang-1400.0.29.51 from Xcode 14.2)
macOS Monterey 12.7.4

References

Another SO question about unnamed LLDB symbols in iOS apps.
LLDB output of any image dump symtab (I tried, but in vain to find relevant LLDB documentation on this).



I’ve tried using a function pointer variable defined using the expr as well, but that only creates an alias (of sorts) to the unnamed symbol, and the unhelpful synthetic name of ___lldb_unnamed_symbolXXX still persists everywhere.

lldb doesn't currently have a user-customizable symbol name substitution feature.  There's no reason it couldn't, but no one has needed this enough to add it.  You can use some of lldb's scripting affordances to add this for various use cases.
For backtraces, you can use the fact that the frame-format setting is customizable, and you can add elements implemented in Python.  So you could remove the ${function.name-with-args} token from your frame-format setting and replace it with a ${script.frame:my_translator:translate}, and in that translate function do the name replacement:
https://lldb.llvm.org/use/formatting.html
You could also make your own python wrapper for disassemble that consults your lookup table first, and then sends the un-cooked name to the actual disassemble command:
https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#create-a-new-lldb-command-using-a-python-function
BTW, if someone were motivated to try adding this to lldb, it would be pretty straightforward to add a function_name() API to the frame recognizer infrastructure in lldb.  Then you could register the recognizer for the ___lldb_unnamed_symbol name, and replace it with the known one.

Thank you so much for your answer! From what I’ve understood, though, both the methods you’ve listed (i.e. a) modifying frame-format to use an on-the-fly substituted value from a custom python snippet, and b) writing a wrapper for the di[sassemble] command that maintains a lookup table and subsitutes on-the-fly) would mean that, wherever else I’d want to use the new name, I’d have to write a wrapper/recogniser/etc. specifically for that too, right? (e.g., say for adding breakpoints)

Would be great if there were something I could do to the in-memory symbol table. How/at what time are those synthetic names generated in the first place? Are they stored in memory like LLDB would store any other symbol name? I’m quite new to LLDB — and executable formats in general — so I apologise for any lack of knowledge of how things work behind the scenes.

The macho object file format has a "function starts" section that lists the start of all "functions" even if their symbol has been stripped.  That is what lldb reads to get these "unnamed" symbols.  But I don't think you want to focus on when these are read in, since you very well might want to add your annotations after the fact.  I think it would be better to have something at a high level in the symbol name lookup that will consult a "user provided name table" to augment what lldb gets from symbols.  Either a name -> name or an address -> name table would work.

You can add custom breakpoint setting algorithms to lldb, so you COULD also work around that.  But you are right, it would be better to solve this problem directly in lldb proper rather than nibbling around the edges in the extant customization affordances.
